# Is 'sea changes' right?

Tags: word-usage, plural-forms

I recently came across this term '[sea change](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/sea-change)'.

**Origin:** from Shakespeare's Tempest

There is ,however, nothing from what I researched, anything on ***sea change*** taking a plural form. For eg, is the below sentence grammatically correct?

> The market is prone to a series of **sea changes**.

Comment: I think it works since after *series* it comes a plural noun. For example, *a series of books/episodes/shows*, etc.

Answer (score 1):

IMO, the phrase *'sea change'* is something that is used to depict a very big change, a very dramatic and completely gigantic change. The sea doesn't change like that without people noticing it. Now this phrase is used to refer an event that doesn't occur all that frequently, maybe once in a life time. Considering that, I don't think it is meant to have a plural form. A *'sea change'* should include a lot of changes. So, instead of using it as *"a series of sea changes"*, how about just using *'sea change'* as it is :

> **The market is prone to sea changes.**

Comment: I'd use *The market is prone to sea changes*, since *changes* is plural.